# No se puede descargar con yum en Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Intento seguir [este tutorial](https://chatbotslife.com/rasa-nlu-on-aws-28d962acbf53) para crear mi primer chatbot. Sin embargo hay un momento en el que me pide utilizar `yum` para instalar un grupo yum, que es un paquete predefinido de software que se puede instalar de una vez, en lugar de tener que instalar cada aplicación por separado:

```
sudo yum groupinstall ‘Development Tools’
```

No conocía de esto, entonces copié y pegué el codigo que ya no funciona porque parece que no hay repos habilitados :

```
 mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/rasa_nlu$ sudo yum groupinstall ‘Development Tools’
 There are no enabled repos.
  Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
  You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>
```

Y no parece funcionar el `apt-get` para Development Tools ...

Comment: Para sistemas operativos basados en debiAn es apt-get, creo que se paquete es el sudo apt-get install build-essential

Comment: Se me olvidó estos paquetes traen para compilar los programas por ejemplo g++